# BeautifulSoup Finding Subdirectories

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out how to find sub-directories on a webpage with BeautifulSoup in Python.  I have an idea on how I would do it.  This is what I had in mind:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="/images/pic.png">images</a>
<a href="google.com">google</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for link in links:
    print a['href']
```

Above would post all links on a page though.  How would I get it to just print back sub-directories like in the example "/images/pic.png"?

Although I want to use beautifulsoup using any other module would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the url to extract directory paths:

```
import posixpath
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a href="/images/pic.png">images</a><a href="google.com">google</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    dirpath = posixpath.dirname(urlparse.urlparse(a['href']).path)
    if dirpath and dirpath != '/':
       print dirpath #NOTE: urllib.unquote_plus() may introduce `/`
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `if` condition for `a['href']`, for example with the assumption that sub-directories will at least have two `/` in the path, you can use `a['href'].count('/') >= 2` as a condition.

Sample:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<a href="/images/pic.png">images</a>
<a href="google.com">google</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for link in links:
    if a['href'].count('/') >= 2:
        print a['href']
```

If you mean relative path by "sub-directories", you can use `a['href'].startswith('/')` as a condition.

Comment: You probably want to change that to `if a['href'].count('/') >= 2 and a['href'].startswith('/'):` just to make sure it is actually a relative path.

Comment: `.count('/')>=2` finds `<a href="http://google.com">` (it shouldn't find it) and misses `<a href="images/pic.png">` (it should find it)